# Central Admin and SSP URLs Not Redirecting to Default.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, central-administration, iis

SP SO ladies & gents, I have an issue that came up on our production server where when you navigate to Central Administration `myhost.gov:8080/` or a Shared Service Provider it will not show `default.aspx` at that url.  When I specify `myhost.gov:8080/default.aspx` however, it works.

In Central Admin I get a **You are not authorized to view this page** and in SSP I get **404**.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just add default.aspx as a default content page in IIS for your web sites?

Step-by-step...

1. Start>Administrative Tools>Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager
2. Expand Web Sites
3. Locate the web sites you need to update, eg. SharePoint Central Administration
4. Right click it, select Properties
5. Click the Documents tab
6. Ensure Enable Default Content page is ticked
7. Click Add, and enter default.aspx

Comment: I'll definitely try this one and let you know... Thanks mucho.