# sharepoint 2013 web application root url doesn't work

Tags: url, redirect

in my sharepoint server 2013 backend i can not go to web application root host name but if i add the default.aspx end of hostname i can see the page.

i mean that;

i can not go to web site if i write that url: 'http://sharepointsite.intra' and it shows 404 error.

i can go to web site if i write that url: 'http://sharepointsite.intra/deafult.aspx'.

in addition to these;

i can go to web application site directly another backend.

Comment: those are the same links. Can you explain further? What does your AAM show?

Comment: oh i m sorry i missed th default.aspx. i edited.

Comment: are you sure that default.aspx is a viable page or in that path? Sometimes it can be pages/default.aspx, or pages/home.aspx, etc.

Comment: yeah it is visible, and page loaded when i write http://site/defult.aspx. the main point of my problem that, "http://site" doesn't redirect default.aspx or home.aspx.

Comment: what is your Alternate Access Mappings?

Comment: all web application are default. this is totaly intranet.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/33461/central-admin-and-ssp-urls-not-redirecting-to-default-aspx there is a solution for this problem but there is no proporties feature in site' iss.

Comment: In IIS Manager, when you click the SharePoint Intranet server, there should be a "Default Document" setting. What does that say? There should be default.aspx

Comment: it is ok. i didn't change this configuration. there is a default.aspx

Comment: I have the same problem. when i try to access the site collection i get a 404 error.
when i add default.aspx to the url, it works.<br>
Did you find any solutions for your problem ?? my sites where working fine for a year and now suddenly i get this problem.it's frustrating !!
<br>Thank you for your Help.

Comment: no i couldn't find a solution. did you try to make a home page button in the ribbon menu?